# How to make a UITextView 50% Transparent colour in Swift

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitextview, alpha

I am trying to make the `UITextView`background colour 50% transparent. I tried setting the `alpha` to `0.5` but it also changed the text alpha to 0.5, which is not what I need, I only need the view to be 50% transparent.

Comment: Did you try setting the text view's background color?

Comment: If you want to do textView's Background Transparent  Follow the steps:        1. set Background  Color property of UITextView to ClearColor.                     2. Set alpha of UITextView to 0.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want just the background color to have transparency but not the text, you can set the background color to have an alpha value less than 100%.

For example, here we have a text field with a white background on a blue background:

[image]

If I select the text view's "Attributes Inspector" and scroll toward the bottom, I can set the background color:

[image]

If we choose a pure red color with 50% opacity, as such:

[image]

Now look at how the text view looks with our 50% red laid over a blue background:

[image]